# pyplot colormap with extend option (in contourf)

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I have a set of data ranging from -0.5 to 2 (for example). I only want to color the data that are within [-0.5,1]. I did something like:

```
from matplotlib import colors as mpl_colors

color_map  =  plt.cm.jet
color_map.set_bad('gray',  1.0)
norm_color = mpl_colors.Normalize(vmin=-0.5, vmax=1, clip=False)
nb_colors = 40
map_frame.contourf(x_mesh, y_mesh, data, nb_colors, cmap=color_map, norm=norm_color, extend='both')
```

I expect the colorbars to have 40 colored strides, ranging from -0.5 to 1.

Instead I get the following image:

[image: Results with weird colorbar]

The colorbar doesnot stop at 1 as expected, like it does for example here: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contourf_demo.html

Do you know why ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.

I don't have your data, so I choose my data as an example.

The temperature at 2 m from model simulation show like this:

[image]

We can see the temp was range from 268.5 to 280.5

To achieve your attempt in analogy, I write some code here:

```
### 1. Mask the location which temperature not in the range of [265,278]

t_mask_1 = np.ma.masked_greater(t,278)
t_mask_2 = np.ma.masked_less(t_mask_1,265) 

### 2. Generate the colormap with  40 colored strides 
cs=plt.cm.jet(np.arange(40)/40.)  

### 3. Plot the contourf figure  
cf  = map.pcolormesh(x, y ,t,40, cmap= plt.cm.jet,alpha = 0.8)
```

[image]

```
cMap = plt.cm.get_cmap("jet",lut=40)    
pc = map.pcolormesh(x, y ,t,cmap= cMap,alpha = 0.8)
```

[image]

Wish it would help!

#### Attention

I also found a question here. By masking the data beyond user-defined range, the `contourf` colorbar would fit the data range decently. But the colorbar of `pcolormesh` seem to be wrong at the bottom with blue strikes less than 270.